# Arch won't recognize keyboard and mouse plugged into a USB hub

Tags: arch-linux, usb, keyboard, mouse

My keyboard and mouse are plugged into a seven-port USB hub. That hub is plugged into my PC.

My PC runs Arch and Windows 10. When I boot up, I can use my keyboard and mouse in my motherboard's BIOS menu, or to select Windows 10 at the bootup menu. If I select Windows 10, I can use the keyboard and mouse just fine when my PC boots to that OS.

But if I select Arch, my keyboard and mouse do not work once the PC boots to  the desktop login screen.

But when I plug the keyboard and mouse directly into my PC, they work on Arch.

When I log into my desktop environment, KDE Plasma, and run `lsusb` in terminal, I see the USB listed.

Before a few days ago, when I updated all my installed packages, there was no issue. But now there is. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a systemd error to me.

According to an open issue, systemd 244.2-1-arch can cause similar behavior : https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/14822

This should be fixed in 245. For now you might consider using a previous version.

Comment: How do I use a previous version?

Comment: You should read carefully https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_packages

Comment: I downloaded the latest update and the problem is fixed.